# Geting max value by multi properties dimesional

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

My data object structure as below

```
data = [
{
    Points: "3",
    Rating: "1.4",
    Person: "Joe"
},
{
    Points: "1",
    Rating: "2.0",
    Person: "Kay"
},
{
    Points: "3",
    Rating: "1.8",
    Person: "Micheal"
}]
```

I am getting result with using underscore.js as below

```
  var maxObject = _.max(data,function(obj){
     return parseInt(obj.Points) && parseFloat(obj.Rating)
    });

    console.log(maxObject.Person);
```

Above code result is "Kay" but I would like to get result as "Micheal"

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer. Working code as below;

```
data = [
{
    Points: "13",
    Rating: "-2",
    Person: "Joe"
},
{
    Points: "13",
    Rating: "200",
    Person: "Kay"
},
{
    Points: "17",
    Rating: "32.8",
    Person: "Micheal"
}];

// sort version
var maxObject = _.first(data.sort(function (a, b) {   
    return parseFloat(a.Points) - parseFloat(b.Points) || parseFloat(a.Rating) - parseFloat(b.Rating);
}).reverse());


// long version
data.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aSize = parseFloat(a.Points);
    var bSize =  parseFloat(b.Points);
    var aLow =  parseFloat(a.Rating);
    var bLow =  parseFloat(b.Rating);
    console.log(aLow + " | " + bLow);

    if(aSize == bSize)
    {
        return (aLow < bLow) ? -1 : (aLow > bLow) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return (aSize < bSize) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}).reverse();

alert(JSON.stringify(maxObject));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hbuc2knj/73/